# Как отсортировать записи по полю из связанной таблицы?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

К примеру есть юзеры и посты, которые создают эти юзеры, как получить все посты отсортированные скажем по дате создания юзера?

Делал таким способом:

```
Post.all.includes(:user).order('users.created_at ASC')
```

Но на production сервере подобный запрос сбрасывает по таймауту, да и вообще отрабатвает неприемлимо долго. Как обойтись без includes?

**Update**

Конкретно мой запрос выглядит так(таким образом joins уже есть):

```
addresses = Address.where(services:{active: true}).joins(:service).joins(:district => :city).joins(:district).includes(:jobs).includes(:addresses_car_models, :car_models)
addresses  = addresses.distinct
```

при добавлении `.order('services.search_priority DESC')` получаю ошибку:

```
PG::InvalidColumnReference: ERROR:  for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list
LINE 1: ...s"."active" = 't' AND "cities"."id" = 1  ORDER BY services.s...
```

Comment: Может попробовать joins?

Comment: И посмотрите вывод `.explain`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Заапдейтил вопрос и тут же нашел ответ:

К основному запросу добавил `.select("addresses.*, services.search_priority")` и все стало работать как надо.